# Basic square generator gives wrong results

Tags: python, generator, square

I've made a generator that is meant to return the first 10 square numbers, but it doesn't seem to be working.

The results are supposed to be

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```

but instead I get

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Here is my code

```
def TopTenSQ():

    n = 1

    while  n <= 10:
        sq = n * n
        yield sq
        n += 1

values = TopTenSQ()

for i in values:
    print(i)
```

Note: I have tried to remove n += 1 and I still get the same result for some reason. is there something wrong with that line?

edit: I've reinstalled python 3.7.0 but I'm still getting the same result. also when typing python --version into cmd I get no result.

Comment: I get the correct results. Did you use copy/paste to put your actual code in the question?  A typo could be deadly.

Comment: I suspect what's happened is that you are running a different version of the code where it yields `n` instead of `sq`. This could happen if you're working in the interactive mode, and you write `values = TopTenSQ()` before changing the definition of the `TopTenSQ` function; in that case `values` is still a generator made from the old function.

Comment: I am suspecting something is wrong with my version because when I type 

python --version 

in my cmd it gives no result. should i try to reinstall it?

Comment: yes, i copied and pasted that code.

Comment: I've reinstalled python 3.7.0 but I'm still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code as is, and it returned what you wanted. So I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: hm. that's so weird.

Comment: I am using Python 3 btw, but I don't see how it would be any different. Are you sure this is exactly the code you are using and it doesn't produce what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the answer but....

I deleted the file, came back to this website, copied the code back into my IDE and it just... magically started to work. problem solved, I guess.